# Bluetooth earbuds on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, earbuds

I have been reading about bluetooth earbuds a lot but can't get my head around few things so asking them here.

I got my new Soundcore Liberty Air 2 Pro wireless earbuds couple of days ago and connected them to my Android phone and they sound amazing both for music and calls.

Problem starts when I connect them to my work PC for zoom conference calls. From what I understand, the only way to use them for calls is to use HSP/HFP profile and they sound awful with that.

My questions:

1. Is there any workaround/hack to make them sound better for zoom voice calls? I have updated my BT and all other drivers on PC.
2. Since these earbuds have ANC, how does that function on HFP profile? I tried couple other earbuds and notice that anything with ANC sounds worse and very loud when using HFP on Win 10.. why is that?
3. Is HFP a Win 10 limitation since Android voice calls sound amazing? What is Android using then and is there any way to use that on Win 10?

Thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=Bluetooth+call+quality

Comment: The usual solution is to get a separate microphone and avoid the hfp profile on the headphones entirely.